# Store a null in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

In an MVC App we are suppose to dynamically load some strings from database. Basically a `<string,string>` key-value dictionary. Loading each text each time from the database would kill the application, so those texts would normally be pulled from the DB just once and then stored in cache (namely `Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache`). There are also default texts that are hardcoded and those would be used if nothing was found in the database. To make things more simple I would also put those default texts in the cache.

The logic is as follows:

1. Try getting the text from cache and return it if it's found.
2. If there was no text in the cache, try pulling it from the databaseand and if it's found, save it to cache and return it.
3. If all above failed, use the default text and save it to the cache so no further queries will be made for this particular key.

If I understand it correctly the only way to check if key is set in `Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache` is by comparing it's value to a null. My problem is, it's not entirely unlikely that the default text will be a null. So if I put that in the cache, I will not know that the key was set and I will try to pull the non-existant value from the database each time the text is needed.

I know I could use an empty string instead of a null, but it's possible that I might need to distinguish between nulls and empty strings for some reason in the near future.

So is there some way to tell if a key is set in the `Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache` when the value assigned is a null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StriplingWarrior beat me to the punch, but I agree with what he said: just wrap what you're storing in a complex type so you can do a null check.  Normally you'd use `Nullable<T>` for this, but you can't use a Nullable type for things that are already considered nullable, like strings.

Here's a practical example:

Define a simple wrapper class:

```
public class CacheEntry<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }

    public CacheEntry(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    } 
}
```

And then use it!

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("name", new CacheEntry<string>("Marcin"));

var name = (CacheEntry<string>) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("name");
if (name != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name.Value);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I should accept StriplingWarrior's answer or yours. I mean, he responded first, his answer is correct and generally same as yours, but yours contains simple self-explanatory code (which I like better and I'm going to use).

Answer (score 2):

`null` is highly overused by most C# developers. If you recognize that these values are *optional* (meaning they may or may not be there), you may want to make your cache entries be of some type that wraps the actual type you're storing. That way, getting a null value means that there is no entry, whereas getting a non-null value that has a null `Value` property on it means it exists in the cache, but its value is null.

Incidentally, I've been working on [a library](https://bitbucket.org/j2jensen/callmemaybe) to represent exactly this sort of wrapper. It's still in its alpha phases at the moment, but at least for this purpose it should be safe to use. You can get it from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CallMeMaybe/) under the name "CallMeMaybe".

```
object result = HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(key);
if(result != null)
{
    return ((Maybe<string>)result).Else(() => null);
}
var value = Maybe.From(GetValueFromDb());
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, value, ...);
return value;
```

Another option would be to use `MemoryCache` directly, which I think is what backs the `HttpContext.Current.Cache` these days, but which provides additional methods like `GetCacheItem`.

Answer (score 1):

If you must store a null in something that doesn't distinguish between nulls and key-not-found conditions, store an "active null" object to represent a null you've actually added:

```
private static readonly object ActiveNull = new object();

public bool GetIfPresent(string key, out object value)
{
    object fromCache = Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get(key);
    if(fromCache == null)
    {
      //failed to obtain.
      value = null;
      return false;
    }
    if(ReferenceEquals(fromCache, ActiveNull))
    {
      //obtained value representing null.
      value = null;
      return true;
    }
    value = fromCache;
    return true;
}

public void AddToCache(string key, object value, CacheDependency dependencies, DateTime absoluteExpiration, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback onRemoveCallback)
{
  Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(key, value ?? ActiveNull, dependencies, absoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration, priority, onRemoveCallback);
}
```

Comment: After thinking  about the problem some more I came up with this idea too, but having read the other answers (for various reasons I was unable to do so until now), a wrapper sounds like an even better solution.